# Exiting/Starting the Terminal (El Capitan)

Tags: terminal, macos, command-line

In the latest Mac OS X Terminal version I noticed that if I type `exit` and the press `Enter`, I get the following:

```
Last login: Wed Jan 27 09:18:48 on ttys000
Ian-iMac:~ Ian$ exit
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

As far as I can remember, previous versions of the terminal, simply closed the window when you entered `exit`.

Is there anyway to restart the same terminal after `[Process completed]` displays? Or should I completely close the window and restart the terminal? It looks like I can't type anything after entering `[Process completed]` displays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the Shell exits, it means that you are done. So one option is to close the window and manually start another one (or you can simply press <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to automatically open another shell).

Another option that can save you some time is to make Terminal automatically close the tab after the exit process has been performed properly.
Open Terminal Preferences > Profiles > Select your profile > Shell tab > When the shell exits --> Close the window. In such a way, if you want to start again your shell (after having exit) you should just open another one.

Comment: In my specific case, I found very useful ^D (ctrl+D)

Answer (score 1):

Once it says "Process Completed", the Terminal's session has been terminated, and there is no way to restart that specific session. You may close the window and open a new one or open a new tab on the same window.